# Image won't display in <Image> in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to load a png image into an Image control in Xamarin Forms. I have added the image to both the drawable and the drawable-hdpi folder, set the BuildAction = AndroidResource and the Custom Tool = MSBuild:UpdateGeneratedFiles. One of the png images I try to use, monkeyface.png, copied from a sample project, loads just fine. The other png image will not display at all. Here are the relevant details:

CODE

```
            <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Image  Source="monkeyface.png" Aspect="AspectFill" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start"/>
                <Image  Source="homepage.png" Aspect="AspectFill" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="End"/>
                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Button Text="Click" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
```

OUTPUT

[image]

IMAGE INFO FOR IMAGE 1

[image]

IMAGE INFO FOR IMAGE 2

[image]

I am going crazy trying to figure this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE
I also tried, with no success, the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="NGIC_XAML.Views.Login.Login">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Image  Source="homepage.png" Aspect="AspectFit"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

But this works:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="NGIC_XAML.Views.Login.Login">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Image  Source="monkeyface.png" Aspect="AspectFit"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

UPDATE 2

```
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable\homepage.png">
      <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateGeneratedFiles</Generator>
    </AndroidResource>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-hdpi\homepage.png">
      <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateGeneratedFiles</Generator>
    </AndroidResource>
  </ItemGroup>
```

And in case someone points out that the image that won't load has the Generator specified, I removed that also and it STILL doesn't load.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable\monkeyface.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable-hdpi\monkeyface.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

the png file in question

[image]

The location of the images in the Android Resources folder

[image]

After removing bin and obj folders and rebuilding, I get the following errors:

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.DesignerProject.set_PreferredTheme(Theme value) in E:\A_work\711\s\Xamarin.Designer.Android\Xamarin.AndroidDesigner\DesignerProject.cs:line 901
   at Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.AndroidDesignerSession.SetTheme(Theme theme, Boolean triggerChange) in E:\A_work\711\s\Xamarin.Designer.Android\Xamarin.AndroidDesigner\AndroidDesignerSession.cs:line 376
   at Xamarin.Designer.Forms.Preview.AndroidXamlRenderer.GetRenderSessionForFormFactor(XamlRenderContext context, XamlFormFactor formFactor) in E:\A_work\711\s\Xamarin.Designer.Forms\Xamarin.Designer.Forms.Preview\Android\AndroidXamlRenderer.cs:line 236
   at Xamarin.Designer.Forms.Preview.AndroidXamlRenderer.d__25.MoveNext() in E:\A_work\711\s\Xamarin.Designer.Forms\Xamarin.Designer.Forms.Preview\Android\AndroidXamlRenderer.cs:line 136
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Xamarin.Designer.Forms.Preview.AndroidXamlRenderer.d__27.MoveNext() in E:\A_work\711\s\Xamarin.Designer.Forms\Xamarin.Designer.Forms.Preview\Android\AndroidXamlRenderer.cs:line 307
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)

Comment: That's interesting. I have just tried downloading the image and placing it only in the  `drawable` folder and it showed just fine. If you are developing for iOS, do you see it there, or is it missing too? Also, did you try deleting the bin & obj folders?

Comment: I deleted the bin and obj folders and now I get error as shown in my latest edit to the post.

Comment: After delete all bin and obj folders in all projects, return to Visual Studio > Clean Solution then restart Visual Studio. If not works, check if your Visual Studio has an update.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set [Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid) number of rows and columns, 
then specify in each child which row and column it should be on. As this example has only one column, it does not need to be specified as good code practice in XAML.

```
<Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="49*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="49*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Image Source="monkeyface.png" Aspect="AspectFill" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    <Image Grid.Row="1" Source="homepage.png" Aspect="AspectFill" HorizontalOptions="Fill" />
    <Button Grid.Row="2" Text="Click" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Look at his edits. His issue is not with the layout (even though it is incorrect). The issue is with the image and how it is being referenced/looked for.

Answer (score 1):

So, after 2 days of frustration in trying to get the png file to display in an Image, and after following all of the great suggestions posted in response to my question, I decided to perform the Visual Studio update from the version I was using, Version 16.6.0, to Version 16.6.1. After the update  finished, I loaded the solution again and LO AND BEHOLD! the image displays perfectly. I still have no definitive reason why it was failing to load before I did the update, but WHO CARES! It loads now and that's all that matters.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with your image, but with your incorrect use of a layout for what you are trying to achieve. If you want the items to be one below the other, then the best layout will be a [StackLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.stacklayout?view=xamarin-forms).

Currently, you are using a [Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid) layout and you have added all of its items without even specifying the row definitions. This way you are just trying to "align" them by their `HorizontalOptions` & `VerticalOptions`, which is not the best approach, since the grid is trying to guess what you want your end result to look like.

If you still want to use a `Grid` for your layout, then I strongly suggest you read thoroughly grid's [Rows & columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid) guide.

Comment: See my update above. Using a StackLayout didn't work either.Using the Grid was just for demonstration purposes. I'm just trying to display the image any way I can at this point.

Comment: Can you also share the occurrences of the file inside your Android csproj file, so that we can see how it is being referenced there?

Comment: See UPDATE 2 in the question

Comment: You don't need to add the MSBuild properties in csproj file. Add them the same way you have added the monkey image.

Comment: Tried that also. See my latest edits to the question.

Comment: Can you try then to see if the image is in the same folders as the monkey one is (hdpi, xxhdpi, etc)? Also, please double check that the image is the one that you want in all folders. Can't really think of anything else...

Comment: Added screenshot of the Resources folders where the images are located

Comment: I'm out of suggestions then. :( If you try to have only the image (without any wrapper around it) and set the image to fill and expand the whole page, I suppose it is still not visible? Just to confirm that the image is with the file and not how the wrapper handles it.

Comment: Yep, tried that too and nothing. I just don't understand it.

Comment: I also tried a resized (smaller) version and a version that had been converted to jpeg, NONE of them will display.

Answer (score 0):

Seeming as this issue comes up for quite a few searches on google for 'missing image issues on iOS Xamarin', another possible solution when you've exhausted all potential layout issues is to clean the solution and rebuild.

In Visual Studio, Right click the project and click Clean.